# Buy multiple of the same product in different sizes

Tags: price, custom-options, shopping-cart-price-rules, quantity

I am creating a store for a brewery. They would like to sell a type of beer in small bottles and large bottles. So on the frontend I would like them to enter a quantity number next to a size option.

For example:

```
BEER NUMBER ONE
|3| x 250ml Bottle
|0| x 500ml Bottle
```

Can anyone suggest how I might set this up in the admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a Grouped product. For this you need to create the different sizes you want to sell as simple products and then create a new Grouped product where you assign the simple products. In the frontend this will allow the user to enter a qty per size to easily order the amount needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how to set it up in the admin and I think you might have to change the phtml file.
In your list .phtml where you have your add to cart button

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

try this piece of code instead

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
         <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
</form>
```